# How can i Disable <select> tags (html dropdown) using asp.net dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

The label works after I select in dropdownlist and I am trying to disable the other dropdown.

But the problem, it fires only when the Submit button is clicked **take note My submit button has no code yet**.

Here is some of my code

in Option.aspx (client side)

```
<select id="ddlgames" class="ddlgame" runat="server">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select One</option>
    <option value="BasketBall">Basket Ball</option>
    <option value="VolleyBall">Volley Ball</option>
    <option value="FootBall">Foot Ball</option>
</select>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownListID="ddlPlayer"CssClass="Player" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPlayer_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList> 
        <asp:Label ID="lblcomment" runat="server" Text="">
        </asp:Label> 
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {  
        ddlPlayer.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Player", Value = "Y" });  
        ddlPlayer.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Non Player", Value = "N" });
    }
}

protected void ddlNameOfReport_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlplayer.SelectedValue == "N")
    {
        ddlgames.Disabled = true;   
        lblcomment.Text = "Games option disabled";  
    }
    else
    {  
        ddlgames.Disabled = true;
        lblcomment.Text = "Games option enabled"; 
    } 
}

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

sorry for wrong grammar :)

Comment: ddlNameOfReport I can't see it in your html hope it will  ddlPlayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another `UpdatePanel` for your dropdown and add `AsyncPostBackTrigger`.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
<select id="ddlgames" class="ddlgame" runat="server">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select One</option>
    <option value="BasketBall">Basket Ball</option>
    <option value="VolleyBall">Volley Ball</option>
    <option value="FootBall">Foot Ball</option>
</select>
</ContentTemplate> 
<Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlNameOfReport" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Your `ddlPlayer_SelectedIndexChanged` must have an `Update2.Update()`

```
protected void ddlNameOfReport_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlplayer.SelectedValue == "N")
    {
        ddlgames.Disabled = true;   
        lblcomment.Text = "Games option disabled";  
    }
    else
    {  
        ddlgames.Disabled = true;
        lblcomment.Text = "Games option enabled"; 
    } 
Update2.Update()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason is ddlPlayer drop-down is in inside a update panel. ddlgame located in outside that update panel.

If you add ddlgame drop-down inside the update panel and change ddlPlayer_SelectedIndexChanged event like this

```
protected void ddlPlayer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddlplayer = (DropDownList)sender;
        if (ddlplayer.SelectedValue == "N")
        {
            ddlgames.Disabled = true;
            lblcomment.Text = "Games option disabled";
        }
        else
        {
            ddlgames.Disabled = true; lblcomment.Text = "Games option enabled";
        }
    }
```

Or if you want to keep that ddlgames out side this update panel then you have to add ddlgames to another update panel and call the yourupdatepanel.Update(); method inside ddlPlayer_SelectedIndexChanged event.